# How to know if a Firestore transaction in Android failed due to exterior document modification or due to client being offline?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

According to the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transaction_failure) transactions fail in the following cases (showing only the question relevant ones):

> - When the client is offline.
> - When the transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again. The transaction is retried a finite number of times.

But in Java, I don't seem to find a way to know which of the cases I run into in my app. I've tried to cast the task exception to see if there were any methods that return the type of exception or any useful info:

```java
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
    ((FirebaseFirestoreException)task.getException()). // Could not find anything useful here
}
```

Comment: If you try to log `task.getException().getMessage()`, what is printed out in the logcat?

Comment: We could not have much information about whole project, however there are 2 possibilities provided by you. One of them says "translation is retried". Isn't it possible to add logs to catch that transaction was retried?